# How can I convert this Processing code to P5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

In Processing i did this:

```
  void turnFacesZ(int dir) {
    for (Face f : faces) {
      f.turnZ(dir*HALF_PI); 
    }
  }
```

I tried this:

```
function turnFacesZ(dir) {
    for (var f; f < faces.length(); f++) {
      f.turnZ(dir*HALF_PI); 
    }
  }
```

and this:

```
function turnFacesX(dir) {
    faces.forEach(function(turnX(dir*HALF_PI)));
  }
```

Although none of them work.

Also,

```
var matrix = new PMatrix3D();
```

What is equivalent to the PMatrix3D library in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first try:

> ```js
> function turnFacesZ(dir) {
>    for (var f; f < faces.length(); f++) {
>      f.turnZ(dir*HALF_PI); 
>    }
>  }
> ```

you missed to initialize the control variable of the loop (`var f=0`). It has to be:

```js
function turnFacesZ(dir) {
    for (var f=0; f < faces.length(); f++) {
         f.turnZ(dir*HALF_PI); 
    }
}
```

---

In the 2nd try

> ```js
> function turnFacesX(dir) {
>    faces.forEach(function(turnX(dir*HALF_PI)));
>  }
> ```

you missed the "current value" argument in the callback function and the call back function has no body:

```
function turnFacesX(dir) {
    faces.forEach( function(f) {
        f.turnX(dir*HALF_PI);
    } );
}
```

---

If you want to do matrix calculations in javascript then you can use a library like [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/).